# Not running at 24 fps in viewport

Tags: animation

My main problem is that I have a character in a scene and the scene is only running at 17 fps in viewport. Everything is turned down to the lowest render settings. I have a i7-9700k and rtx 2070 super. Is there something I can change to get better performance or do I need to get a different cpu?

Thank you.

Comment: Without being able to look at the blend file I have no idea why your scene is running slow.  Can you add it to your question? Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the scene the animation won't necessarily run at full frame rate when viewed in the viewport even with EEVEE but will be the correct frame rate when rendered to a movie file and played back.

Comment: The scene is not complex at all. it is just one character with about 28,000 faces. I am in studio material view and I have higher poly count animations run at 24fps in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

When I animate a simple plane (32 quads) with a cloth modifier, musgrave, wave and white noise texture, it impacts my FPS tremendously. As Weird Workshop pointed out, I've never seen anything above 60fps running a GTX 1080 TI :)

The only scenario where my PC comes to a screeching, kicking and crying stop is when trying to animate something with a complex shader or even a simple shader for that matter with microscopic details. Especially the first time. Do you have anything like that in you scene?